# How can I create an 'ostream' from a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

In C++, if I have a socket, how can I create an ostream object from it?

I have googled some example:
http://members.aon.at/hstraub/linux/socket++/docu/socket++_10.html

And I have tried:

```
 sockbuf sb(sockfd);
 std::ostream outputStream(&sb);
```

But I can't find the .h file and the library to link with for 'sockbuf'. Is that part of a standard c++ library?

Answer (score 19):

The site you found is a third party non-standard library. There is no standard C++ socket library.

However, if you want as closest to a standard (and powerful!) solution, you should try [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It has been proposed for inclusion in the standard library (TR2). Here's an iostream based example:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream("www.example.org", "http");
stream << "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.boost.org\r\n\r\n" << std::flush;

std::string response;
std::getline( stream, response );
```

However, you'd gain much more if using the Asio's Proactor for asynchronous operation.

Comment: @Chris, I learned to love and value it after working 1 year writing commercially a C++ server, and then seeing how easy it is with Asio :)

Answer (score 6):

Standard C++ (at least C++98) does not deal with networking in any way. So, you have to do something platform-specific.

Some platforms have IOStreams implementations that allow you to create a stream from a file descriptor. In that case, use the socket descriptor as your file descriptor.

Comment: +1: I'd never think of actually passing a `fd` to an iostream O.o

Comment: I am writing my application on ubuntu. Does it has IOStreams which allows me to create a stream from a socket? How can I look for that?

Comment: @silverburgh: GCC 3.4 onwards, so I hear, has `__gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf`, which you can use for that. This article is worth paying attention to: http://www.synflood.at/blog/index.php?/archives/456-One-word-of-warning-about-stdio_filebuf.html

Comment: Thanks. But after reading that link, and google more about it, I think stdio_filebuf is for file not for socket.

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the standard C++ library. Download Socket++ here: http://members.aon.at/hstraub/linux/socket++/ (it was a few directories back from what you pasted)