# Basic Named Pipe to send data between c++ programs?

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, c++14

I  know this has been asked before but I just can't find the answer so I am posting for some help.

I have a DLL, which once injected into a process creates a named pipe. The pipe will wait until a client is connected and will send data to the client until the client disconnects.

The client side, it will just connect to the pipe and receive data and do things with such data.

My question is, I want to be able to send more than 1 type of data, for example, float, int, strings, etc. How do I reconstruct the data into correct data (float, int strings and such)?

Here is my code for the client :

```
HANDLE hPipe;
DWORD dwWritten;
char Buffer[1024];

hPipe = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL);
if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    WriteFile(hPipe,
        Buffer, //How do I put all the data into a buffer to send over to the client?
        sizeof(Buffer),   // = length of string + terminating '\0' !!!
        &dwWritten,
        NULL);


    CloseHandle(hPipe);
}
```

The Server :

```
wcout << "Creating Pipe..." << endl;

HANDLE hPipe;
char buffer[1024];
DWORD dwRead;


hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe"),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
    1,
    1024 * 16,
    1024 * 16,
    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
    NULL);
while (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
    {
        while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
            /* add terminating zero */
            buffer[dwRead] = '\0';

            /* do something with data in buffer */
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
}
```

My problem is, I have a bunch of data I would like to send to the client in 1 go, which could contain things like float, int, double, etc. Once I gather all the data from the server, I would like to send it to the client and have the client parse it by splitting the data like so :

```
void split(const string& s, char c,
    vector<string>& v) {
    string::size_type i = 0;
    string::size_type j = s.find(c);

    while (j != string::npos) {
        v.push_back(s.substr(i, j - i));
        i = ++j;
        j = s.find(c, j);

        if (j == string::npos)
            v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
    }
}
```

I'm sort of lost on how I can send all my data over to the client and correctly get the original value?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I only posted the function I am using, I can add in the main() function and the #include if that is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a library that converts your data to something that can be sent over a socket. This is called a serializer! You can use a serializer also for serializing into a data stream or maybe also in a GUI or whatever. To receive the data, you simply need to "deserialize" it.

You can find a lot of serializer libraries like:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html
- https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/
- and many, many more!

The custom code can look like ( pseudo code! ):

```
class Check
{
    int i;
    float f;

    template<SERIALIZER_TYPE>
    void Serialize( SERIALIZER_TYPE& ser )
    {
         ser & i & f;
    }
 };

 int main()
 {
     Check c;
     std::string s;

     Socket socket( ip, port );

     WriteSerializer   ser(socket);
     ser & c & s;
 }
```

As you can see, you have nothing to write yourself for "knowing" how data types are serialized. Classes/structs have to provide a serializer method, so they can also be split into their native data types.

**Edit:** Added question from comments:

> Is it possible to send this data from my DLL to the EXE through [a] named pipe instead of saving the file?

For `cereal` taken from the docs:

> cereal comes with excellent standard library support as well as binary, XML, and JSON serializers. If you need something else, cereal was written to be easily extensible for adding custom serialization archives or types.

So, one option is to write the new interface for your needs.

But take a look at the example code:

```
void x()
{
    std::ofstream file( "out.xml" );
    cereal::XMLOutputArchive archive( file ); // depending on the archive type, data may be
                                        // output to the stream as it is serialized, or
                                        // only on destruction
    archive( some_data, more_data, data_galore );
}
```

As you can see, there is used a `std::ofstream` as output. So you can simply use that `ofstream` which is opened for a socket.

How you can connect a std::ostream with a socket is answered e.g. here:
[How can I create an 'ostream' from a socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204458/how-can-i-create-an-ostream-from-a-socket)

But it is quite simple to do this job also by hand. You must write your own buffer class for the socket and connect it to an `ofstream`. Not more then ten lines of code, I believe!

As a result, you can stream now your variables and objects as XML, Json, or whatever over a socket.

Edit: From the comments: Yes, using a pipe instead of a socket will also be adaptable to `iostream` and the technique is exactly the same and based on implementing something around `streambuf`.
[c++ connect output stream to input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410961/c-connect-output-stream-to-input-stream)

I hope that on Windows it will work the same way and `istream` is also as `ostream` adaptable.

Going more into the details of a complete solution will not fit here in Q&A style I believe. So, if there are further questions about connecting something to `iostream`, please start a new question!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, from the Cereal quick start page, I see that it saves data. Is it possible to send this data from my DLL to the EXE through named pipe instead of saving the file? (It saves as either XML, JSON, or Binary. (http://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html)

Comment: @TheNewbie: added some more how to write to something different as a file.

Comment: This fails to acknowledge, that pipes in Windows are, well, pipes. Not sockets. While pipes can operate in message-mode, you still have to account for partial messages. Besides, your explanation for *"serialization"* is limited, focused on your proposed use case only. Serialization is much broader: It is the process of translating structured information so that it can be transmitted as a stream to be reconstructed later.

Comment: @IInspectable: `you still have to account for partial messages`. Absolutely! Some of the serializer libs are aware of the problem and provide special "data types" to keep track on complete data packages. If not, the user has to take care of complete packages and must wait for completeness and/or split if multiple, maybe last one partial, packages can be received. But this is the same case also if you write handcrafted code for that.  So there must be something that we have "atomic" data transfer.

Comment: Pipes in message-mode provide atomic transfer of messages. For every read you get at least one full message. If the intermediate buffer is too small, the read will return an appropriate code. This is very different from sockets. Hence my comment that talking about sockets when the OP is asking about pipes is rather unhelpful.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sorry that I miss pipes/sockets/files and did not give special hints for pipes here. But I did not give any media specific hints here. My intention was to show that serialisation of c++ data is a common task which was already done by many people so that libraries are available. That the media must be adapted, like for pipes, can bus, usb, serial link, field bus, what ever, yes, thats absolutely correct. So I beg your pardon that I used a socket in my example pseudo code! But I believe it is possible to adapt a pipe to ostream also.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for pipes. Explaining how to use a serialization library (which is likely not even necessary) fails to answer that question. The whole point of a Q&A site is to provide answers to questions. The point is not to answer a different question and assert, that the answer could be adapted to address the question being asked.

Comment: @IInspectable: I already added a link to my answer. And again: Sorry for that again again and again!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) API to write to pipe, then you can send Buffer of bytes. I like @Klaus idea about serialization to pack all your data and if I need to send objects over pipe from client to server it would be my implementation of choice.

However I consider it overkill if you need to send just some pair of data (like "abc 1.12345"). I would simply put them in the buffer with known delimiter and send from server to client, and then just parse the string on the client.

Answering on your question "//How do I put all the data into a buffer to send over to the client?"

Here's some code snippets:

```
std::string strToSend;
// ... some initialization
std::wstring wstr = std::wstring(strToSend.begin(), strToSend.end());
LPTSTR pchStr = wstr.c_str();
LPCTSTR pchSend;
StringCchCopy( pchSend, 1024, pchStr );
```

Use `pchSend` in `WriteFile(hPipe, pchSend, ...` call.

Please also check the following example for some code ideas: [Named Pipe Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the snippet. I tried to test it out and I am getting 2 errors. `a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPTSTR"`

And : `argument of type "LPCTSTR" is incompatible with parameter of type "STRSAFE_LPWSTR"`

Comment: I need your project to say exactly what is going on. Based on the errors you need `#include <strsafe.h>`, it's where `StringCchCopy` declared (2nd error). `wchar_t*` is actually same as `LPTSTR`. It depends what environment you are using. You have to use LPCTSTR and LPTSTR anyway to operate with API calls so it might be you need to do string -> LPTSTR conversion by yourself: check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532855/how-to-convert-from-wchar-t-to-lpstr)

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to understand what is a pipe here. Pipe and Queue are medium for communication between multiple process. Every message you submit/drop in a queue or pipe  are unique as one set of message and while you are reading it, will read only one message at a time. If you put `10`, `20.45` and `“Hellow”` into a pipe and read them from a client it will read `10` as first message `20.45` as second message and `“Hellow”` as third message. Normally they will be coming a string value which you need to convert into appropriate type. You should have your own logic to check whether a value is `int` or `float` or a normal string. First just read the data and print them all and think how to cope up with them.

Comment: I was going to combine all the data together as a string with a split character like "#". Example: name#age#foo#bar -- Then I would just split at the #, and select which value I want, like [1] would be age, and I just convert it back to int